# Hiding container won't hide content inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone please explain to me why

```
$(".transaction_history_tab").hide();
```

will not hide both

```
// Container
<tbody class="transaction_history_tab">
</tbody>

// In example this is inside the transaction_history_tab container
<div class="data-info-box">
   <span>NO DATA TO SHOW</span>
</div>
```

After hiding `transaction_history_tab` the "NO DATA TO SHOW" still appears.

```js
$(".transaction_history_tab").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// Without table tags around
<tbody class="transaction_history_tab">
  <div class="data-info-box">
    <span>NO DATA TO SHOW</span>
  </div>
</tbody>
```

Working with the answer from [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614628/3296661)

```js
$(".transaction_history_tab").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// With table tags around
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="transaction_history_tab">
    <tr> 
      <td>
        <div class="data-info-box">
          <span>NO DATA TO SHOW</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is solely caused by invalid HTML. The `tbody` element must be contained within a `table`. As yours is not, it isn't rendered. You can see this if you check the DOM in the inspector. The `tbody` can only contain `tr` elements too. The child `div` is therefore also a problem, it should be wrapped in a `tr` and then a `td`.

As the `tbody` element is not rendered, and the `.transaction_history_tab` doesn't exist, hence there's nothing to hide.

To fix the issue correct your HTML. Either add a `table` around the `tbody`, including a `tr` and `td` around the `div`, or remove the `tbody` completely.

```js
$(".transaction_history_tab").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>This will be shown...</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="transaction_history_tab">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="data-info-box">
          <span>NO DATA TO SHOW</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Also a tbody may _only_ contain `<tr>` elements as direct descendants-- [tbody](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've just updated my question and the theory of having `table` around the tbody still doesn't work.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett did you add the `tr` as well?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Correct, i've added tr around it

Comment: And a `td`? I updated my answer to show you the correct HTML

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because structure `tbody>div` without a table/rows/cells is not a valid HTML structure.

Try either using a `table>tbody>tr>td>div` structure as in this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u58460ot

or use just the div without tbody as parent

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
 <tbody class="transaction_history_tab">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div class="data-info-box">
       <span>NO DATA TO SHOW</span>
     </div>

    </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

try like above it will work...

Answer (score -1):

You haven't included your css here, but it is possible that your css includes something like this:

```
.data-info-box {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

which would need changing to:

```
.data-info-box {
    visibility: inherit;
}
```

This is because a child element set to 'visible' will still show up, even if their parent is 'hidden'. Setting the visibility to 'inherit' means that the child will take on whatever visibility attribute the parent has.

'Inherit' is the default setting for visibility, so if this is the problem you would have had to manually set it to 'visible' in your css (or dynamically in your js).